# Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:

Tags: android, flutter

tengo este problema. configurando andoid studio y flutter.
ejecuto esto comando

```
flutter doctor
```

me ocaciona este error

```
Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:
error: insufficient permissions for device: user in plugdev group; are 
your udev
rules wrong?
See [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] for more 
information
```

ya instalae kvm

```
grep kvm /etc/group
```

kvm:x:131:ashe

[image: f]

Comment: Si puedes ejecuta los comandos adb devices -l y lsusb en consola y comparte los resultados si quieres para mas información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualmente el **Android SDK 29** está presentando problemas. La solución es descargar el directorio platform-tools de la SDK 28. Recomiendo descargarla de alguno de estos enlaces, dependiendo de tu sistema operativo:

Windows: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-windows.zip
macOS: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-darwin.zip
Linux: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-linux.zip

Ante todo, es recomendable hacer un backup del actual directorio "platform-tools", la cual se encuentra, si es Windows, en: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk, guardas el respaldo en un lugar seguro. A partir de acá puedes descomprimir según los enlaces facilitados, luego cambias el nombre a la carpeta descomprimida por "platform-tools", la copias, y la pegas en el directorio Sdk, anteriormente señalado, recuerda dar click a Reemplazar. Inicia Android, aplica `flutter doctor` y verifica que tenga Android SDK 28.x.x. Ya con esta acción funciona correctamente.